# React Native + Redux, setup with Express backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I have a ReactJS website linked with redux and Axios to an Express backend. Now I have to build a React Native app from this site, but I want to use the same backend and database. Online I found that Redux + Axios functions can be used in React Native too! But can I use the same code from my ReactJS site to implement Redux functions on my app? I found the action/reducer functions are most of all the same, but can I use a Redux store like the one below (my ReactJS store) to create a store in my app?

```js
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers';

const initialState = {};

const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore( rootReducer, initialState, compose(
    applyMiddleware(...middleware),
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
));

export default store;
```

There are some particular rules I must follow or some setting I need to implement in my app to make it work properly?

Comment: Yes, you can. Remove the `window.` calls and instead use Flipper or React Native Debugger for debugging.

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: should I add a proxy to my backend in package.json like my React site?